# How to draw something on UIImageView in UIViewController Class

Tags: iphone, ios, ipad

I know a method to draw on iPhone using UIView class and UIImage method. But can i draw inUIViewController class on UIImageView?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As UIImageView is a subclass of UIView, you should be able to use the exact same method to do what you want.

You might also add a custom view (inherit from UIView) above any other view and draw anything you want on that view.

Comment: i cannot do it on UIViewController sub class ?